# eslint-loader/index.js Cannot read property 'range' of null

Tags: webpack, eslint

I'm trying to determine if the below problem is caused by a mistake in my config files, or some kind of bug in ESLint; and ultimately how to fix it.

*ESLint version*: 5.9.0

*Error Text*:

`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of null
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

*Cause of error*:

On line 117 of `eslint/lib/rules/template-curly-spacing` a function called `getFirstToken` is called. this function calls `getOneToken` which is found on line 55 of `eslint/lib/token-store/forward-token-cursor.js` Here is what that function looks like:

`getOneToken() {
        return (this.index <= this.indexEnd) ? this.tokens[this.index] : null;
    }`

For some reason, the `index` value of `this` (ForwardTokenCursor) is out of range of the `this.indexEnd` this is what the ForwardTokenCursor looks like right before eslint returns the error: 
`{current: null, tokens: Array(1188), index: 1092, indexEnd: 1090 }`

As you can see, the getOneToken function will return null to the getTokenBefore later on, when a supposed property of this null object is accessed, it causes the linter to error out. Why might this be happening? I assume it's an issue with the way I have eslint set up, although I don't know why that would cause this kind of error. Regardless, I have included my configuration information here.

webpack.config.dev.js:

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('../paths');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.config.common.js');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('../../scripts/create_react_app_utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const getClientEnvironment = require('../env');
const fs = require('fs');

// process.env.API_ENV = 'mock';
const env = getClientEnvironment('');

module.exports = merge(common, {
   entry: [
      require.resolve('../../scripts/create_react_app_utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
        require.resolve('../polyfills'),
      /* require.resolve('react-error-overlay'), */
        paths.appIndexJs
   ],
   output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/main-react.chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath),
   },
   mode: 'development',
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: [
                    {
                        options: {
                            formatter: eslintFormatter,
                        },
                        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
                    },
                ],
                include: paths.appSrc,
            },

      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.bmp$/,
          /\.gif$/,
          /\.jpe?g$/,
          /\.png$/,
      /\.scss$/,
        ],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
        sourceMap: true
            },
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss', // https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#complex-options
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    '>1%',
                    'last 4 versions',
                    'Firefox ESR',
                    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                  ],
                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [{
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
          }, 
          {
            loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          }, 
          {
            loader: "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              data: '@import "globals";',
              includePaths: [path.resolve(paths.appSrc, "./styles")]
            }
          }]
      }
    ]
  },
   plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ]
});
```

.eslintrc

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "React":true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "extends": "airbnb",

    "rules": {
        "max-len": 0,
        "one-var": 0,
        "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["warn", "error"]  }],
        "no-mixed-operators": 0,
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", {"max": 2}],
        "no-prototype-builtins": 0,
        "class-methods-use-this": 0,
        "padded-blocks": 0,
        "no-return-assign": 0,
        "no-unused-expressions": ["error", { "allowTernary": true }],
        "camelcase": 0,
        "no-plusplus": ["error", { "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true }],
        "prefer-destructuring": ["off"],


        "no-tabs": 0,
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "error",
        "indent": ["error", "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
        "new-cap": 0,
        "spaced-comment": ["error", "always", { "exceptions": ["*"] }],

        "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
        "import/no-unresolved": 0, // Linting will not interpret aliases if this rule is turned on
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
        "import/extensions": 0,

        "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": 0, //Allow us to put event handlers on any HTML element
        "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-tabindex": 0,


        "react/forbid-prop-types": [2, { "forbid": ["any"] }],
        "react/jsx-indent": [2, "tab"],
        "react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", "tab"],
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
        "react/jsx-no-bind": 1,
        "react/prefer-stateless-function": [1, { "ignorePureComponents": true }],
        "react/sort-comp": 0
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true
        }
    }

}
```

Let me know in comments if any other config or build files are needed. I appreciate your help, I have found a couple bug tickets on the eslint github that appear to be related to this problem, but they were closed and seemingly unresolved. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9872

Comment: Just a note for anyone else who comes across this error, I still haven't quite cracked it, but I'm 100% sure that it's not a problem with ESlint There's something wrong with my webpack configuration which is causing the error. I haven't figured out what it is, but this particular error message and stack trace weren't super helpful.

Comment: have you found the answer yet? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your ".eslintrc" config file add

```
.."rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2, {
      "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral"]
    }]
or
    "index": "off"
```

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-template-literals/